# Azure Functions Dependency Injection Failing Again

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, autofac, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an Azure V2 application running in Azure. For about the 3rd time now over various releases my custom dependency Injection is failing again!

This time it is worse than ever as the issue only happens when it is deployed to Azure and the logging was a **nightmare** to find out what was happening.

Azure Functions is currently running as follows with the usual error that it is unable to index my Functions.

```
018-11-10T10:41:56.091 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "ad-api-dev",
  "state": "Default",
  "version": "2.0.12165.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12165.0 Commit hash: f9d6c271296eaae48f933c67d1df796fd4ff2a94"
}
2018-11-10T10:41:57.607 [Information] Initializing Host.
2018-11-10T10:41:57.607 [Information] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
2018-11-10T10:41:57.644 [Information] Starting JobHost
2018-11-10T10:41:57.655 [Information] Starting Host (HostId=ad-api-dev, InstanceId=387865be-cfdf-45ca-98ba-2e0091827461, Version=2.0.12165.0, ProcessId=5140, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=True, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2)
2018-11-10T10:41:57.674 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2018-11-10T10:41:57.723 [Information] 15 functions loaded
2018-11-10T10:41:58.158 [Information] Generating 15 job function(s)
2018-11-10T10:41:58.237 [Error] Error indexing method 'CompleteSimulation.Run'
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException : Error indexing method 'CompleteSimulation.Run' ---> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot bind parameter 'executionService' to type IExecutionService. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexMethodAsyncCore(MethodInfo method,IFunctionIndexCollector index,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs : 277
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexMethodAsync(MethodInfo method,IFunctionIndexCollector index,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs : 167 
   End of inner exception
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexMethodAsync(MethodInfo method,IFunctionIndexCollector index,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs : 175
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexTypeAsync(Type type,IFunctionIndexCollector index,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs : 103
2018-11-10T10:41:58.574 [Warning] Function 'CompleteSimulation.Run' failed indexing and will be disabled.
```

My local version runs fine as below

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.2.32 Commit hash: c5476ae629a0a438d6850e58eae1f5203c896cd6)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12165.0
[10/11/2018 13:35:15] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed: False
[10/11/2018 13:35:15] Reading host configuration file 'Y:\src\modo.solutions\Modo.Esg.Api\ModoSol.Functions.Api\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\host.json'
[10/11/2018 13:35:15] Host configuration file read:
[10/11/2018 13:35:15] {
[10/11/2018 13:35:15]   "version": "2.0"
[10/11/2018 13:35:15] }
[10/11/2018 13:35:17] Initializing extension with the following settings: Initializing extension with the following settings:
```

You can see I am using the same runtime version locally as Azure, So if anyone knows why my Dependency Injection would work locally but not when deployed it would be appreciated.

I am using Autofac 4.8.1 as my dependency injection container.

Thanks in advance.

BTW If anyone else has that issue of not being able to see why their Functions host is not starting follow these instructions.

- Go into the Portal for your Azure function and find and enable the Live Log Streaming.
- While this window is open re-deploy/publish your app.
- Once thats done go into cloud explorer (Visual Studio Windows only :/) and find the logs.

If you don't have the live log streaming window open while you deploy you don't get any logs!!!

Screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: What version of WindowsAzure.Storage are you using?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg WindowsAzure.Storage version is 9.3.2

Comment: I have finally managed to get this working again but by moving from a custom inject attribute to using a service locator pattern. Which I am not very happy about.   It's odd as its the same autofac container. Also don't get why it works locally and only failing when deployed

Comment: I've had something similar that was caused by a certain version of this package: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/794

Comment: I think you are posting on the wrong post, this is about dependency injection, I had another post similar to that issue.

Comment: I mention it because the package seems not to be stable.

Comment: I know it is not relevant but dont do DI using serverless... it is pointless.. At least this is my thinking

Comment: Can you share your code that breaks, and then the code that works?